# d3 set image visibility=hidden onerror

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I hide an svg:image when onerror is fired?

```
node.append('svg:image')
    .attr("x", "-30px")
    .attr("y", "-40px")
    .attr("width", "60px")
    .attr("height", "80px")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
        return 'https://somedomain.com/images/' + d.name;
    })
    .attr("onerror", function(d){
      console.log('The image ' + d.name + ' failed to load');
      // this.style("visibility", "hidden");
      // d.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, the code would look something like this:

```
.on("error", function() {
  d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

That is assuming that the element you want to hide fires `error` events.